# Website redirecting to other website when opened with https

Tags: dns, cross-domain, http-redirect

My website is redirecting to some other website when I do not open it using `https`. what could be the issue?

Comment: Check for redirect property given in htacess file or the server where the website is hosted.

Comment: @Shruti if my answer solved your problem, please accept it. And, if not let me know what went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux cPanel**

If you are the admin of your website, then login and modify your `.htaccess` file located in your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

[Refer here](https://in.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828)